# Plots/Graphs by Group in R

Tags: r, plot

I would like to create plots/graphs by Group for the dataset shown below.

```
    Type    Group   price
1   Fair    Cut 4405.202
2   Good    Cut 4053.888
3   Very Good   Cut 4175.925
4   Premium Cut 4779.045
5   Ideal   Cut 3654.54
6   D   Color   3485.46
7   E   Color   3291.415
8   F   Color   3760.281
9   G   Color   4091.388
10  H   Color   4610.674
11  I   Color   5083.602
12  J   Color   5173.224
```

In particular, I want to create a graph with `"price"` on the vertical axis and `"Type"` on the horizontal Axis for the `Group = "Cut"` and similar graph for the `Group="Color"`. I have more groups in my dataset and I would like to automate this process for all the other groups. I have tried several options including using ggplot with facet wrap by Group but the graphs I get from ggplot are not unique for each Group.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Regards,
Philip

Comment: Can you show some code that you have implemented ?

Comment: In addition to @sid's comments, can you make your example reproducible? Here area few tips on how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Read the data:

```
df <- read.table(text="Type    Group   price
Fair    Cut 4405.202
Good    Cut 4053.888
Very_Good   Cut 4175.925
Premium Cut 4779.045
Ideal Cut 3654.54
D   Color   3485.46
E   Color   3291.415
F   Color   3760.281
G   Color   4091.388
H   Color   4610.674
I   Color   5083.602
J   Color   5173.224", header=TRUE)
```

Load the `ggplot` package:

```
require(ggplot2)
```

Creating a facetted plot:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Type,y=price)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(Group~.) + 
  theme_bw() # making the plot a little more pretty
```

Subsetting the data inside `ggplot` for a plot of only one group:

```
ggplot(data=df[df$Group=="Cut",], aes(x=Type,y=price)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="grey90", color="blue") + # making plot look better with 'fill' & 'color' parameters
  theme_bw()
```